# How to check on the if statement for the contain text on PHP dom?

Tags: php

I'm stored the website link in MYSQL database where I can output the data in PHP and I'm using PHP DOM to extract the data. I have output the text which I got "CBS This Morning: Saturday NEW" using this code:

```
<?php
  define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');
  define('DB_USER', 'myusername');
  define('DB_PASSWORD', 'mypassword');
  define('DB_DATABASE', 'mydbname');

  $errmsg_arr = array();
  $errflag = false;
  $link = mysql_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD);

  if(!$link) 
  {
    die('Failed to connect to server: ' . mysql_error());
  }

  $db = mysql_select_db(DB_DATABASE);
  if(!$db) 
  {
    die("Unable to select database");
  }

  function clean($var)
  {
    return mysql_real_escape_string(strip_tags($var));
  }
  $channels = clean($_GET['channels']);
  $id = clean($_GET['id']);

  if($errflag) 
  {
    $_SESSION['ERRMSG_ARR'] = $errmsg_arr;
    echo implode('<br />',$errmsg_arr);
  }
  else 
  {
    $insert = array();

    if(isset($_GET['channels'])) 
    {
      $insert[] = 'channels = \'' . clean($_GET['channels']) .'\'';
    }
    if(isset($_GET['id'])) 
    {
      $insert[] = 'id = \'' . clean($_GET['id']) . '\'';
    }


    if($channels && $id) 
    {
      $qrytable1="SELECT id, channels, links FROM tvguide WHERE channels='$channels' && id='$id'";
      $result1=mysql_query($qrytable1) or die('Error:<br />' . $qry . '<br />' . mysql_error());

      while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result1))
      {
        $links = $row['links'];
        include ('simple_html_dom.php');
        $html = file_get_html($links);
        $title1 = $html->find('li[id=row1-1]', 0)->plaintext; // with this

        if ($html->find('li[id=row1-1]', 0)->plaintext == ('NEW'))
        {
          $output = preg_replace('/\d:\d+/', '', $title1);
          $output = '<span id="title1">'.str_replace(array("\t", '   ', '<BR>','</BR>', 'AM','PM'), '', $output).'</span><br><br>';
          $output = str_replace('<span id="title1"> ', '<span id="title1">', $output);
          $output = str_replace(' "', ': ', $output);
          $output = str_replace(' NEW', '', $output);
          echo $output;
      }
    }
  }
?>
```

Here's the HTML source:

```
<span id="title1">CBS This Morning: Saturday  NEW</span><br><br>
```

In this case, I'm trying to look for a contain text at the end whether if the conttain text have a text called "NEW" then it will be replaced to an empty text. I tried to use it with `if ($html->find('li[id=row1-1]', 0)->plaintext == ('NEW'))` to look for a contain text before do something, but it doesn't check it out. I think I might have done it wrong, but I'm not really sure. Does anyone know how I can check for a contain text at the end of the text using if statement so I can replace the contain text to an empty text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`==` does an exact match of the entire string. You need to use a function that searches for a substring:

```
if (strpos($title1, 'NEW') !== false) {
    ...
}
```

If you only want to recognize it at the end of the title, you can use a regular expression:

```
if (preg_match('/NEW$/', $title1) {
    ...
}
```

or you could use `substr()`:

```
if (substr($title1, -3) == 'NEW') {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help barmar, this is what I really wanted. Problem solved!